# Is it possible to store whole object in struts session?

Tags: java, struts, httpsession

I'm developing an struts App.
In one of the actions I instantiate an object, once instantiated i need that object to be available in other actions for the user using the App.

Is there a way to store a whole object in the http session in Struts 1.3?

Comment: You didn't explain why do you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can store and retrieve any object.

In Action1 use:

```
  private ArrayList<Integer> obj= new ArrayList<Integer>();
  .............
  session.setAttribute("objname", obj);//to store
```

In Action2 use:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> obj1= (ArrayList<Integer>)session.getAttribute("objname");//to retrieve
```

Syntax:

```
 setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object value)
```

Comment: but keep in mind, that all objects stored in the HttpSession must be Serializable.

Comment: and you must know that OP shouldn't do such things, because the scope of the object is not a session scope.